# Output producing 4 images side by side for single image provided in gradient calculation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Following code is used to calculate the normalized gradient at all the pixels of image. But on using imshow on calculated gradient, instead of showing gradient for provided image its showing gradient of provided image 4 times (side by side).

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat mat2gray(const Mat& src)
{
    Mat dst;
    normalize(src, dst, 0.0, 1.0, NORM_MINMAX);
    return dst;
}
Mat setImage(Mat srcImage){

    //GaussianBlur(srcImage,srcImage,Size(3,3),0.5,0.5);
    Mat avgImage = Mat::zeros(srcImage.rows,srcImage.cols,CV_32F);
    Mat gradient = Mat::zeros(srcImage.rows,srcImage.cols,CV_32F);
    Mat norMagnitude = Mat::zeros(srcImage.rows,srcImage.cols,CV_32F);
    Mat orientation = Mat::zeros(srcImage.rows,srcImage.cols,CV_32F);
    //Mat_<uchar> srcImagetemp = srcImage;
    float dx,dy;
    for(int i=0;i<srcImage.rows-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<srcImage.cols-1;j++){
            dx=srcImage.at<float>(i,j+1)-srcImage.at<float>(i,j);
            dy=srcImage.at<float>(i+1,j)-srcImage.at<float>(i,j);
            gradient.at<float>(i,j)=sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
            orientation.at<float>(i,j)=atan2(dy,dx);
            //cout<<gradient.at<float>(i,j)<<endl;
        }
    }

    GaussianBlur(gradient,avgImage,Size(7,7),3,3);
    for(int i=0;i<srcImage.rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<srcImage.cols;j++){
            norMagnitude.at<float>(i,j)=gradient.at<float>(i,j)/max(avgImage.at<float>(i,j),float(4));
            //cout<<norMagnitude.at<float>(i,j)<<endl;
        }
    }
imshow("b",(gradient));
waitKey();
return norMagnitude;    
}
int main(int argc,char **argv){
Mat image=imread(argv[1]);
cvtColor( image,image, CV_BGR2GRAY );
Mat newImage=setImage(image);
imshow("a",(newImage));
waitKey();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your incoming source image is of type `CV_8UC1`, and yet you read it as floats:

```
dx=srcImage.at<float>(i,j+1)-srcImage.at<float>(i,j);
dy=srcImage.at<float>(i+1,j)-srcImage.at<float>(i,j);
```

If running under the debugger, this should have thrown an assertion, which would have highlighted the problem.

Try changing those lines to use `unsigned char` as follows:

```
dx=(float)(srcImage.at<unsigned char>(i,j+1)-srcImage.at<unsigned char>(i,j));
dy=(float)(srcImage.at<unsigned char>(i+1,j)-srcImage.at<unsigned char>(i,j));
```